# Exception when connecting to Azure EventHub

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have created an Azure Event Hub and am getting an exception when the following line of code is executed.

```
ConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder(namespaceName, eventHubName, sasKeyName, sasKey);
```

I get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/time/Duration
at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.MessagingFactory.<clinit>(MessagingFactory.java:29)
at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ConnectionStringBuilder.<init>(ConnectionStringBuilder.java:92)
at camelTest.Send.main(Send.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.Duration
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Would somebody be able to tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EventHubs Java Client needs - jdk 1.8.
I believe you are trying to run with jdk 1.7 - which might compile - but while running it - it will run into a lot of NoClassDefFound errors.